# How to get user_id f,facebook_id: ,facebook_access_token usin new facebook sdk

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Now new facebook sdk support oath concept. so i am confuse to getting these variable.
Any help or documentation will be appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/   http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the appropriate doc.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

You should be able to access:

```
{
status: 'connected',
authResponse: {
    access_token: '...',
    expiresIn:'...',
    signedRequest:'...',
    userID:'...'
}
}
```